# Prevent Google Indexing Specific Content

Tags: jquery, html

I have some content that i want to prevent Google Indexing because its duplicated across a few sites.

I understand I can use a `robots.tx`t file to do this but the content doesn't exist on its on URL.

Let me explain the content:

When a user clicks on a button `jquery.load()` will load a DIV with this content that is brought to the front of the page (z-index) kind of like a popup. The main 2 parts are a Join and Help section.

Is there a way for me to prevent indexing?

Its kind of like preventing indexing of a DIV or prevent indexing on a button click.

---

The content is not on the page to start with...

Its in a seperate PHP file which jquery requests if the user clicks on a link/button.

Once that button/link is clicked its loaded into the DIV that resides in the DOM.

Comment: The question is where the actual content (which you want to preserve from indexing) is stored. In other words, is there an alternative path how a robot can request it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most search engines do not execute javascript while indexing. So your lazy loaded content will not be indexed. It's a different story if your div is present in the html code and will become visible later.

As Stan pointed out (see comments) the Google search indexer can execute javascript. I was however unable to find proper documentation or an official statement by Google (Please post a comment if someone should find one). Because it is not properly documented and Stan's sources say that **some** js / AJAX content will be indexed i can only recommend not to rely on the indexing of dynamic content. There is no way to predict or verify the outcome.

If you want your content to be properly indexed the right (compatible) way to do this would be:

- Create pages that display the content without javascript
- Create an XML sitemap and hand it in via [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)

By having a separate pages for each content that you want to index you have very granular control over what is indexed and what is not.

Comment: +1 for mentioning hidden/loaded content, you just beat me to it ;)

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant because it's about Custom Search. As for Google Bot, you're wrong - [it can handle JavaScript generated content](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1807658).

Comment: Your link is dead. I'm aware that javascript can be evaluated to some point, but i wouldn't go so far and actually rely on it. (Bad Source: http://searchengineland.com/google-can-now-execute-ajax-javascript-for-indexing-99518 )

Comment: @Stan: Alright, the link is working now. Your source clearly states 'Now has the ability to execute AJAX/JavaScript to index some dynamic comments'. 'Some' is too vague and I would rather like an official statement by google for this. Also: Simply because it's possible in theory, doesn't make it a best practice. The way i described is the most structured, effective and safe way to do it.

Comment: The problem with your reasoning is that the OP should have a guarantee that dynamic content will not be indexed by Google Bot. In your answer, you state that it "do not execute javascript". But this is in fact just the contrary. It can do, and we don't know for sure whould it index the concrete dynamic content of the OP or not. So you answer is unacceptable, imho.

Comment: Very well... i shall correct my statement to say that indexing of javascripted content is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

So what I can get out of that you don't want a page to be indexed by google so it's kind of said in their docs but heres a link that describes it better than I could

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710

and some code

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

if you add this to your page that you dont want indexed, this code is saying to the google 'robots' do not index this page :-D